# Redis instantaneous_ops_per_sec higher than actual throughput

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

We are using Redis as a Queue which has on an average about **~3k rps**. But when we check the instantaneous_ops_per_sec, this value consistently reports higher than expected, by about 20%, in this case, reports ~4k ops per sec.

To verify this, I have taken a dump of MONITOR for about 10 seconds and checked the number of incoming commands.

```
grep "1489722862." monitor_output | wc -l
```

Where 1489722862 is the timestamp. Even this count matches with what is being produced in the queue and what is being consumed from the queue.
This is a master-slave redis cluster setup.
Does **instantaneous_ops_per_sec** also account for the slave reads? If not, what is the other reason for which this count is significantly higher?

Answer (score 0):

The `instantaneous_ops_per_sec` metric is calculated as the mean of the recent samples that the server took. The number of recent samples is hardcoded as 16 by `STATS_METRIC_SAMPLES` in `server.h`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not very clear on this. If i always take the most recent 16 samples, how can the count be always higher than the "wc -l" of MONITOR command?